# How do I define the size of an ELF symbol defined in NASM assembly sources?

Tags: assembly, linker, nasm, elf

I have a project where I mix C++ and assembly, and most things are fine until I start dealing with linker shenanigans.

I implemented a stack tracing method, and I developed a function to walk a compile-time-generated symtab table.

The compile time generated symbols only include T-type symbols (in .text section and global). However, I use plenty of non-global functions, and so I changed the filter to t-type symbols (no need to be global). I know how to define the ELF size field for global symbols in NASM; how do I do it for non-global symbols?

Comment: The manual only seems to mention globals.

Comment: That's inconvenient: I'd prefer not to have to export all my symbols. :P

Comment: What does this question have to do with C++?  If nothing specifically relates to C++ please remove the tag.